# Test accuracy much higher than validation and train accuracy

Tags: neural-networks, validation

My test accuracy is around 20% greater than validation accuracy and the train accuracy. I have read a few posts and some suggest that there might be something wrong with the split.
In the below code I do a stratified split, so class imbalance shouldn't be an issue.
Is it possibly underfitting?

```
  # 60% TRAIN, 20% TEST, 20% VALIDATION
        features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42,stratify=labels)
        features_train, features_val, labels_train, labels_val = train_test_split(features_train, labels_train, test_size=0.25,
        random_state=42,stratify=labels_train)
```

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: Shape of the dataset is (2000000,80). Should I be using a different split than 60/20/20?

Comment: The split is fine, and the dataset is large enough. If the test performance is higher than the train performance, there is something weird going on. How balanced are your classes? (what is the mean of the target?) If you dont use the stratify argument, does anything change? What is the difference between your test and validation set? Look at the statistics of the columns and look for any kind of descrepency or data leakage.

Comment: I agree with @ChristopherCollins that there is something weird that shouldn't be happening with such a large dataset.  In addition to his suggestions, what happens if you just repeat this on different random splits?